# Nginx not loading css/js/images in https - Blocked loading mixed active content

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I am running **Ubuntu 14.04** with **Nginx 1.8.0**.

While opening the web pages in https the pages appear to be broken as the `css/js/images` don't load.

```
Error: 'Blocked loading mixed active content'
```

This is my [nginx.conf](https://github.com/adithyakhamithkar/ansible/blob/master/roles/nginx/templates/nginx.j2)

This is my [virtual host file](https://github.com/adithyakhamithkar/ansible/blob/master/roles/nginx/templates/virtualhost_ssl.j2)

Could some one please guide me how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

It probably means you are serving web pages that include explicit links to `http://...` instead
of `https://...` or just `//...`.  See [these stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18251128/5008284) answers.